# ¿Como obtener el UUID de bluetooth en un dispositivo Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

Para establecer una socket connection a mi dispositivo via bluetooth necesito obtener el identificador UUID del "servidor".

Por parte del cliente puedo obtener lo UUID´s mediante el método [getUuids()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getUuids()) de [BlueToothDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html)

> [getUuids()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getUuids()) Devuelve las características admitidas (UUID) del
>   dispositivo remoto.

```
BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
ParcelUuid[] uuids = device.getUuids();
```

Pero deseo obtener la  `UUID` del mismo dispositivo. Investigando en realidad no existe un método expuesto del SDK para este proposito.

¿Existe alguna opción?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La obtención de los UUID designados al dispositivo se puede obtener mediante ["reflexión"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexi%C3%B3n_(inform%C3%A1tica)) mediante el mismo método [getUuids()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getUuids()) , para esto debemos tener habilitado BlueTooth en nuestro dispositivo.

```
   try {
    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Method getUuidsMethod = BluetoothAdapter.class.getDeclaredMethod("getUuids", null);
    ParcelUuid[] uuids = (ParcelUuid[]) getUuidsMethod.invoke(adapter, null);

         if(uuids != null) {
             for (ParcelUuid uuid : uuids) {
                 Log.d(TAG, "UUID: " + uuid.getUuid().toString());
             }
         }else{
             Log.d(TAG, "Uuids no encontrados, asegura habilitar Bluetooth!");
         }

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

De esta forma se puede obtener el o los UUID relacionados al dispositivo con el siguiente formato:

```
0000XXXX-0000-X000-X8000-00X0XXXXXXXX
```

esto para ser usado como identificador:

```
private static final UUID deviceUUID = UUID.fromString("0000XXXX-0000-X000-X8000-00X0XXXXXXXX");
```

No olvidar declarar el permiso dentro del archivo `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

probar:

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

Method getUuidsMethod = BluetoothAdapter.class.getDeclaredMethod("getUuids", null);

ParcelUuid[] uuids = (ParcelUuid[]) getUuidsMethod.invoke(adapter, null);

for (ParcelUuid uuid: uuids) {
    Log.d(TAG, "UUID: " + uuid.getUuid().toString());
}
```

Comment: gracias amigo, encontré que hasta el día de hoy se puede con reflexión, saludos!!!